# Use Bottomshet with Collapsing Toolbar in Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet-behavior

I'm pretty new with CoordinatorLayout, currently I'm having a problem to implement the layout as following:
[image: First image]

This is the initial layout, the blue part is AppBarLayout (it contains CollapsingToolbarLayout), green part is a view e.g LinearLayout, the red part is the BottomSheet

.
[image: Second image]
The second image here is when user drags the Bottom sheet upwards. The AppBarLayout will shrink and the Bottom sheet will expand.
[image: Third image]
At this point, if the user continues dragging Bottom sheet upwards, it will expand fully and cover the Views (green part).
If anyone has any idea, please give me some suggestions. Thank you very much!

Comment: Show your codes. See Also Material Design BottomSheet.